# Easy way to extract raster cells OUTSIDE a vector (Mask) layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins

I have a raster file but am only interested in the cells outside a certain polygon. This polygon is very iregular and scattered across the raster. Is there any easy way to extract only the cells outside of this polygon? A sort of "reverse clip" command? I have zero knowledge of python. I am using QGIS. I need a code-free solution.

Comment: Use reversed logic and update the cells inside your polygon to nodata value with raster calculator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new shapefile that contains a single polygon that covers the whole extent. Then you can take the difference between your irregular polygon and the single polygon (Vector menu --> GeoProcessing Tools --> Difference). Now with this result you can Clip your raster by Mask Layer (Raster menu --> Extraction --> Clip Raster by Mask Layer).

Comment: How to do this with ArcGIS Pro?